# Regex returns empty character space and undefined?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a array of string which includes double quotes with in in it.

```js
let str = `He is a "man of his" words always\ "single quote"`;
console.log(str);
let re5 = /((["]).*?\2|\S+)/g;
let abc = str3.split(re4);
console.log(abc);
```

Expected result, 
['He', 'is', 'a', '"man of his"', 'words', 'always\', '"single quote"']

But I am getting

[ '',  'He',
  undefined,
  ' ',
  'is',
  undefined,
  ' ',
  'a',
  undefined,
  ' ',
  '"man of his"',
  '"',
  ' ',
  'words',
  undefined,
  ' ',
  'always',
  undefined,
  ' ',
  '"single quote"',
  '"',
  '' ]

Help needed correcting the above regex, I am not getting the reason behind this empty string space and undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either match `"`, eventually followed by `"` again, or match one or more non-space characters:

```js
let str = `He is a "man of his" words always\ "single quote"`;
console.log(str.match(/"[^"]+"|\S+/g));
```

When you have capture groups with `split`, every capturing group gets included in the result. You have 2 capturing groups, so for every match, the items in those groups are included. (If the capturing group isn't matched at all for one particular match, the result is `undefined` - which occurs, for example, when the capture group is in one alternation, but the pattern follows the other.) Regardless, using `.match` is much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your time Your code works fine but special charcter \ is missing.

Comment: Your input string does not have any literal backslashes in it, and you said: Expected result, `['He', 'is', 'a', '"man of his"', 'words', 'always', '"single quote"']`. If your input string *does* have a literal backslash in it, and if your expected result also has that backslash in it, you should edit the question

Comment: Sorry my bad, I missed it. Edited my question.

Comment: You still don't have any literal backslashes in the input: `'always\ "' === 'always "'`